# Delphi notify events from interfaces

Tags: delphi, interface

I'm here again for a question about notification.
I've the followinf interface:

```
unit TblInterface;

interface

uses
  System.TypInfo, Vcl.Forms, RzPanel, Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages,
  UserMessages, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Controls;

type

  TFrameType = (ftList, ftDetail);

  TFrameInfo = record
    Frame: TFrame;
    FrameType: TFrameType;
  end;

  TFrameClass = class of TFrame;

  ITabella = interface
  ['{D21924F9-BB41-493B-B06D-0908C0CA73D8}']
    function GetCurrentActiveFrameType: TFrameInfo;
    procedure CreateLstFrame(ParentForm: TForm; Frame: TFrameClass);
    procedure CreateDtlFrame(ParentForm: TForm; Frame: TFrameClass);
    procedure DestroyLstFrame;
    procedure DestroyDtlFrame;
    procedure BringFrameToFront(FrameType: TFrameType);
    procedure OnDoubleClick;
  end;

  TTabella = class(TInterfacedObject, ITabella)
  private
    FLst: TFrame;
    FDtl: TFrame;
    ActFrame: TFrameInfo;
    function GetCurrentActiveFrameType: TFrameInfo;
    procedure CreateLstFrame(ParentForm: TForm; Frame: TFrameClass);
    procedure CreateDtlFrame(ParentForm: TForm; Frame: TFrameClass);
    procedure DestroyLstFrame;
    procedure DestroyDtlFrame;
    procedure BringFrameToFront(FrameType: TFrameType);
    procedure OnDoubleClick;
  end;

implementation

{ TTabella }

{ Creazione frame lista }
procedure TTabella.CreateLstFrame(ParentForm: TForm; Frame: TFrameClass);
begin
  FLst := Frame.Create(ParentForm);
  FLst.Parent := ParentForm;
  FLst.Align := alClient;
end;

{ Creazione frame dettaglio }
procedure TTabella.CreateDtlFrame(ParentForm: TForm; Frame: TFrameClass);
begin
  FDtl := Frame.Create(ParentForm);
  FDtl.Parent := ParentForm;
  FDtl.Align := alClient;
end;

{ Distruzione frame lista }
procedure TTabella.DestroyLstFrame;
begin
  FLst.Free;
end;

{ Distruzione frame dettaglio }
procedure TTabella.DestroyDtlFrame;
begin
  FDtl.Free;
end;

{ Porta in primo piano il frame richiesto }
procedure TTabella.BringFrameToFront(FrameType: TFrameType);
begin
  case FrameType of
    ftList: begin
      FLst.BringToFront;
      ActFrame.Frame := FLst;
    end;
    ftDetail: begin
      FDtl.BringToFront;
      ActFrame.Frame := FDtl;
    end;
  end;
  ActFrame.FrameType := FrameType;
end;

{ Restiruisce il frame attivo }
function TTabella.GetCurrentActiveFrameType: TFrameInfo;
begin
  Result := ActFrame;
end;

procedure TTabella.OnDoubleClick;
begin
  BringFrameToFront(ftList);
end;

end.
```

In the interface I create two frames that are used to display list and detail of some database tables.
Form interface I create, brig to front the correct frame and destroy it.
At this point I need to notify events to the frames created, but I don't know how to do this king of job.
For example I need to notify to the detail frame that a button was pressed in the list frame.

How can I achieve this task?

Comment: you write "Form interface I create, brig to front the correct frame and destroy it". When do you destroy it? In the OnDoubleClick? It's not clear from your code. 

Are the frames out of your control? Do you manage them? If so, you could subclass a TFrame and add a method to be called by the ListFrame

Comment: I've two frames for any table: one for list records and one for show record detail. They are created dinamically when the user select the table to manage so I don't know what is contained in the frame. Destory is used when the user close the form that hosts the frames

Comment: If I get it correctly, the user selects a table, and gets the List frame and then he or she selects a record in the List frame and sees the details in the Details frame, correct?

Comment: Yes John, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways to do that.
First, which i will recommend, is using another Interface; Second way is using procedure of object, which we handle event.
Let's put the hands in the batter!

1. Declare a new Interface before ITabella with the methods will want to notify

   ```
   IProcessor=Interface
   {Shift+Ctrl+G}
   procedure Select; 
   procedure Search();
   ```

A very basic example to handle Click event and same Search event, to call the frame ftList
Then we implement the methods in descendant classes

```
TProcessTabellaPeople=class(TnterfacedObject,IProcessor)
procedure Select; virtual; abstract;
procedure Search; virtual; abstract;
..
end;
TProcessTabellaCustomer=class(TProcessTabellaPeople)
procedure Select; virtual; abstract;
procedure Search; virtual; abstract;
..
end;
{remove abstract clause to implement the methods using Shift+Ctrl+C,
or keep them to late binding in descendant Classes}
```

Add a reference to IProcessor in ITabella

```
ITabella = interface
  ['{D21924F9-BB41-493B-B06D-0908C0CA73D8}']
    fProc:IProcessor ;
    function GetCurrentActiveFrameType: TFrameInfo;
    procedure CreateLstFrame(ParentForm: TForm; Frame: TFrameClass);
    procedure CreateDtlFrame(ParentForm: TForm; Frame: TFrameClass);
    procedure DestroyLstFrame;
    procedure DestroyDtlFrame;
    procedure BringFrameToFront(FrameType: TFrameType);
    procedure OnDoubleClick;
    **procedure clickSelect;**
    **property Proc:IProcessor read fProc write fProc;**
  end;
```

Propagates TTabela.OnDoubleClick for corresponding IProcessor method

```
procedure TTabella.OnDoubleClick;
begin
  BringFrameToFront(ftList);
  If Assigned(fProc) then Proc.Search(); {Call IProcessorMethod}
end;
procedure TTabella.ClickSelect;
begin
If Assigned(fProc) then Proc.Select(); {Call IProcessorMethod}
end;
```

using the interface properly
On Create of TTabela pass the Processor, for example

```
Var Tabella1: ITabella;
Begin
Tabela1:=TTabela.create();
Tabela1.proc:=TProcessor
end;
```

At this point I will recommend to you implement the constructor create passing the `IProcessTabellaCustomer.create;` {don't need to free using Interface vartype}

For onClick of `TButton` do like that:

```
Tabela1.ClickSelect;
```

2. Use procedure of object contents or `TNotify` class methods
   You can declare ClassMethods like this

   ```
   TSelectMethod = procedure(name:String; Sender:TObject) of object;
   ITabella = interface
   ['{D21924F9-BB41-493B-B06D-0908C0CA73D8}']
   property Select:TSelectMethod read fSelect write fSelect;
   property Search:TNotifyEvent;
   end;
   ```

Note that `TNotifyEvent` signs

```
TNotifyEvent= procedure (Sender:TObject)of Object;
```

While in the form you create some methods with the same signs of Events Handler,

```
procedure TForm1.btnSearchClick(Sender:TObject)of Object; //*the same sign of TButtonClick, for example*
begin
end;
procedure TForm1.ShowSelected(name:String; Sender:TObject) of object;//*customized sign with new parameters
begin
showmessage(Format('Selected name%s',[name]));
end;
```

You can attribute the procedures for fields in run time

```
Tabella1:=TTabela.create();
Tabella1.Select:=Form1.btnSelectClick;
Tabella1.Search:=Form1.btnSearchClick;
```

Comment: At the second way, the property "Select:TSelectMethod read fSelect write fSelect;" gives a compiler error (E2168 Field or method identifier expected), and at interfaces fileds are not allowed. I guess this is a mock example and not a real one.